# Trying to pass files from a subfolder to a new folder after Filtering

Tags: python, shutil, fnmatch

I am trying to make a code that allows me to copy files from various subfolders to a new folder. The main problem and why it wasn't a straight forward thing to deal with since the beginning is that all the files start the same and end the same, just 1 letter changes in the file that I need.

I keep getting an error saying: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '20210715 10.1_Plate_R_p00_0_B04f00d0.TIF'"

So far this is what I have:

```
import os,fnmatch, shutil
mainFolder = r"E:\Screening\202010715\20210715 Screening"
dst = r"C:\Users\**\Dropbox (**)\My PC\Desktop\Screening Data\20210715"

for subFolder in os.listdir(mainFolder):
    sf = mainFolder+"/"+subFolder
    id os.path.isdir(sf):
        subset = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(sf), "*_R_*")  
        
for files in subset:
    if '_R_' in files:
        shutil.copy(files, dst)
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I just saw an error which was a copy paste mistake --> if os.path.isdir(sf): noot ----id os.path.isdir(sf):

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you aren't providing the full path to the file to `shutil.copy`, so it assumes the file exists in the folder you are running the script from. Another issue the code has, is that the `subset` variable gets replaced in each loop before you are able to copy the files you matched in the next loop.

```py
import os, fnmatch, shutil
mainFolder = r"E:\Screening\202010715\20210715 Screening"
dst = r"C:\Users\**\Dropbox (**)\My PC\Desktop\Screening Data\20210715"
matches = [] # To store the matches

for subFolder in os.listdir(mainFolder):
    sf = mainFolder + "/" + subFolder
    if os.path.isdir(sf):
        matches.extend([f'{sf}/{file}' for file in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(sf), "*_R_*")]) # Append the full path to the file
            
        
for files in matches:
    shutil.copy(files, dst)
```